# Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]:require () of ES Module C:\users\LENOVO\Desktop\backe

Tags: node.js, react-fullstack

My node js is trailing node package manager and this error is still there, `error require jsm`
How to solve it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.